# How to point isometric camera to the center of cube in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, geometry

I am struggling with an excercise question and maybe you could help me.
I have to set up a camera and cube with THREE.js. The cube should keep its initial ratio and the camera should look at the center of the cube. 
I think I managed to do a isometric projection but I can't figure out how to point the camera to the centre.

Here's what I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Cube</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-3,3,3,-3, 0, 100);


        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
        scene.add(ambientLight);
        var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
        light.position.set(-10, 10, 10);
        scene.add(light);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(800,800);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff }));
        scene.add( cube );

  function render() { //this is to be used for animation later
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
        camera.position.x=1;
        camera.position.y=1;
        camera.position.z=1;

        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
        renderer.render( scene, camera);

        }
 render();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats what lookAt can be used for. In your case the position of the cube equals its center, so the answer is:

`camera.lookAt( cube.position );`

http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/135/

Comment: Can this be represented as a vector? Maybe 
     `camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));` ?

Comment: ```cube.position``` is a ```THREE.Vector3```. Your cube is located at ```(0,0,0)``` so this is already correct :-)